# "extconf.rb failed" message while installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie here. I've searched for other similar questions on the site but still wasn't able to solve the problem. I've installed Ruby 2.0.0 and RubyGem 2.0.3, but when I'm trying  to install Rails 4.0.0 I got:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:814:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/yuanhunglo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

I tried to install Rails by

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the set up or if I still need to install something. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have the standard development tools installed on this (presumably linux) system?  Like the c compiler, etc.  What linux are you running?

Comment: error message section that you have posted is not informative, instead of this post the upper section of error message

Comment: **"You have to install development tools first."**

Comment: I'm running OS 10.8 Mountain Lion, and I've just updated Xcode to 4.6.3 (I'm assuming this is the standard development tool?)

Comment: Agarie beat me to it.  He has the answer you need.

Comment: I installed Command Line Tools, but even with the compiler installed I still get the same error message. Does this mean I need to reinstall some things? Maybe compiler's not the only problem?

Comment: I'm getting this issue and I already have the development tools installed. Crazy thing is, it goes away if I use an RVM gemset and ruby. But my manual Ruby 2.0.0 installation dies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using OSX.

This error happens when you can't compile some extensions, in this case due to the lack of a compiler ("You have to install development tools first"). Open App Store, download XCode and, after installing it, click on "XCode" on the menu, go to Preferences -> Downloads -> Components and download "Command Line Tools".

Comment: I thought this was what I needed, but after I downloaded Command Line Tools from Xcode and installed it I still got the same error message. Maybe it's not a problem with the compiler? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, what happens after you type "which gcc" on your command line?

Comment: it returns 

`/usr/bin/gcc`